# How to add table cells independent from other cells?

Tags: html, css, cell, css-tables

I want to add bottom cells to the table. However, when I add the cells, the upside cells shrink. How do I accomplish to add independently table cells?  link is here

http://jsfiddle.net/gzC4e/`

here I want to add independent cells but upper cells shrink. I don't want upper side cells to shrink while adding new cells to bottom row.

```
.enalt
{
display:table-row;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `.enalt` to `position:absolute;`

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gzC4e/1/

Comment if you need more help.

Comment: no problems, if you are happy with the answer please accept it thanks, good luck :)

Comment: I dont know how to accept it. I will do it as soon as I know. Thanks again.

Comment: It has a big tick with grey border right below downvote and upvote! :)